# Why was RSSurfaceView class deprecated so fast?

Tags: android, renderscript

RSSurfaceView class was created in API 15 but deprecated and hidden in API 16, why deprecated so fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The feedback we got from internal and external app developers was that they preferred to use OpenGL directly because of familiarity & portability either through our Java bindings or NDK.

(from [this Android Developers discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/m194NFf_ZqA))

Comment: Is there any tutorial how to port from RSSurfaceView to OpenGL?